# Invalid status line when trying to download file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to download xml from URL from c# code, so i can then load it into datatable.

I tried this very simple code

```
public static void run() {
    string url = "http://www.strava.cz/foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=0000";
    var xml = XDocument.Load(url);
}
```

which should work, however, when i run it, it throws error `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Received an invalid status line: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250" standalone="yes"?>'.`

i also tried downloading it with httpclient diriectly instead:

```
public static async Task run() {
    string url = "http://www.strava.cz/foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=0000";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

however it crashes with the exact same error code, that the status line is invalid (the thing it tries to parse as status line is the first line in the downloaded xml file)

How could I fix this crashes?

Edit:
I tried downloading the file with curl, and it threw http 0.9 not allowed. I then tried allowing --http0.9, and it showed the contents of the file correctly. [i also looked at the response header thats shown in firefox, and it shows version http 0.9.](https://i.imgur.com/cv4BI4X.png)
Could it be just that .NET doesnt support this old version of HTTP?

Comment: The error is correct. The server sends an invalid response without any response headers. Not even a status code. As Jon Skeet says, that server or rather the FoxISAPI addin is broken.

Comment: `.NET doesnt support this old version of HTTP?` nothing does, not even curl. That's why you got an error. HTTP 1.0 came out in 1996. 0.9 was written in 1991 and had no headers at all, neither request nor response. It only supported HTML documents. `--http0.9` effectively tells curl to treat the entire response as a single HTML page

Comment: BTW that kind of server is worthy of a computing museum exhibit, and that's not a joke. FoxPro ISAPI returning raw XML with a non-Unicode encoding. That was a rare combination even in 2001. Just running the ISAPI filter would require an old 32-bit version of IIS.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP server is broken, basically.

If you visit that URL with a browser, while recording TCP/IP traffic with Wireshark or similar, you'll see that the response is given directly - no initial status line, headers etc.

You could potentially obtain the data with `TcpClient`, but while it's violating HTTP, I suspect you won't be able to use `HttpClient` or similar. (It would be good to let the hosting service know that it's broken...)

Comment: FoxPro ISAPI, returning raw XML with non-Unicode encoding and no headers. I haven't seen or heard of such a combination since Don Box gave the SOAP talk from a bathtub

Comment: This makes you wonder what kind of IIS and hardware is used to run an ancient Fox Pro ISAPI filter.

Comment: > (It would be good to let the hosting service know that it's broken...)
yeah they propably wont fix it, since its legacy software... I am trying to download the food menu from the StravaCZ system, and there are 2 versions, a new system made in .NET, and this old legacy system that uses Visual Fox Pro... Which they dont update anymore and is used only for places that are already using it and which didnt upgrade yet.
And how could TcpClient be used?

Comment: "And how could TcpClient be used?" By connecting to port 80, sending "GET /foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=0000 HTTP/1.1" and then "Host: www.strava.cz", then capturing what is sent back.

Answer (score 0):

It's Normal , it does not work that link. Are you sure that url active is ?  When you get that link from url variable which is( **http://www.strava.cz/foxisapi/foxisapi.dll/istravne.istravne.process?xmljidelnickyA&zarizeni=0000**) it seems not working.Try to work on the browser ,you are going to see that it's not working.

This code line waits an xml file output

```
   var xml = XDocument.Load(url);
```

Bu the page is not active.

Check the Url

Comment: "Try to work on the browser ,you are going to see that it's not working" - I don't know about your browser, but the browser I'm using copes with the response being malformed...

Comment: The URL works in browser properly (Tested in firefox pc and mobile). ¨But since the webserver that serves this file is on HTTP 0.9 then it want to get loaded by modern c#

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely caused by the server, it can be reproduced outside the .NET (like Postman). See below response status validation is failing within HttpClient/HttpConnection.

[image]

[image]